# SWIG const char* setter

Tags: java, c++, swig, setter

I work on the Java wrappers for shared library written in C++ using SWIG. In the library there is an union that looks similar to this:

```
union Union{
    int f_int;
    double f_double;
    bool f_bool;
    const char* f_string;
    MyObject* f_my_object;
};
```

I wrap this union and SWIG generates the getters and setters to all fields in the Union.

But when I run SWIG I get the warning:

```
Warning 451: Setting a const char * variable may leak memory.
```

I understand why it is so, because there is an explanation in the SWIG documentation: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html (Chapter 5.5.4).

My question is: is there any trick to avoid the memory leak while wrapping const char* type. I have to deal with this type, because I can't make any changes in the library sources.

I'll be thankfull for any help.

EDIT

I have an idea how to fix the problem, but I'm not sure if it's correct. But first more details about the problem:

SWIG generates the C code for const char* union member setter that looks like this:

```
SWIGEXPORT void JNICALL Java_example_exJNI_Union_1f_1string_1set(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jstring jarg2) {
  Union *arg1 = (Union *) 0 ;
  char *arg2 = (char *) 0 ;

  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  (void)jarg1_;
  arg1 = *(Union **)&jarg1; 
  arg2 = 0;
  if (jarg2) {
    arg2 = (char *)jenv->GetStringUTFChars(jarg2, 0);
    if (!arg2) return ;
  }
  {
    if (arg2) {
      arg1->f_string = (char const *) (new char[strlen((const char *)arg2)+1]);
      strcpy((char *)arg1->f_string, (const char *)arg2);
    } else {
      arg1->f_string = 0;
    }
  }
  if (arg2) jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jarg2, (const char *)arg2);
}
```

The problem is in line:

```
arg1->f_string = (char const *) (new char[strlen((const char *)arg2)+1]);
```

As SWIG documentation says:

> When variables of type const char * are declared, SWIG still generates functions for setting and getting the value. However, the default behavior does not release the previous contents (resulting in a possible memory leak).

So I think I should force SWIG to generate C code that looks like this:

```
SWIGEXPORT void JNICALL Java_example_exJNI_Union_1f_1string_1set(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jstring jarg2) {
  Union *arg1 = (Union *) 0 ;

  static std::string* arg2_ = new std::string();

  const char *arg2 = (const char *) 0 ;

  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  (void)jarg1_;
  arg1 = *(Union **)&jarg1; 
  arg2 = 0; 
  if (jarg2) {
    arg2 = (const char *)jenv->GetStringUTFChars(jarg2, 0);
    if (!arg2) return ;
  }
  {
    if (arg2) {
      &(arg2_)->assign(arg2);
      jenv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jarg2, (const char *)arg2);
      arg1->f_string = arg2_->c_str();
    } else {
      arg1->f_string = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Does it solve the memory leak problem? I think yes, but maybe i overlook something.

And I wonder how to force SWIG to change this and only this function to look like I want to. Should I use some typemaps or something else?